# Firefox picture tag support?

Tags: html, firefox, retina

I'm trying to use `picture` tag in Firefox. [caniuse.com says that `picture`](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture) supported in Firefox 33 (beta) and I can enable support in Firefox 32 (current) manually.

I opened an [example from html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/) and I can see that it doesn't work. Also I tried on my own http://vm-0.krasulya.kd.io/. There are requests only to basic image (`src` attribute) in webinspector network panel.

Both examples work in Chrome Canary.

According to http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/edits.html#the-picture-element HTML is correct.

Does FF support `picture` at all?

**UPD**

Here is my markup:

```
<picture>
    <source
        src="1.jpg"
        type="image/jpeg"
        media="(min-width: 300px)"
        srcset="1.jpg, 2.jpg 2x"/>
  <img 
    src="1.jpg" 
    srcset="1.jpg, 2.jpg 2x">
</picture>
```

Comment: You should include the code you tried *in the question itself*. A link is not enough.

Comment: Your own test page refers to nonexistent images.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, sorry, updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suddenly `scrset` attribute is still disabled by default in Firefox (even Nightly, see [bug #870021](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=870021)). To enable it, go to `about:config` and set `dom.image.srcset.enabled` value to `true`.

Here’s the page to test it: http://pepelsbey.net/pres/picture/demos/retina.html

There’s also `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` flag which could be set to `2.0` to test retina on non-retina device.